# Where is Binder/ProcessState.h located?

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk, stagefright

I am trying to build IJKmediaplayer with libstagefright. But I am encountering an error.

`Config.log` says:

```
arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -D_ISOC99_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Dstrtod=avpriv_strtod -DPIC -O3 -Wall -pipe -std=c99 -ffast-math -fstrict-aliasing -Werror=strict-aliasing -Wno-psabi -Wa,--noexecstack -DANDROID -DNDEBUG -march=armv7-a -mcpu=cortex-a8 -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-a8 -std=c99 -fPIC -mthumb -pthread -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -c -o /tmp/ffconf.ofpI5mq2.o /tmp/ffconf.EKPBn1tK.cpp
cc1plus: warning: command line option '-std=c99' is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
cc1plus: warning: command line option '-std=c99' is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
/tmp/ffconf.EKPBn1tK.cpp:1:33: fatal error: binder/ProcessState.h: No such file or directory
 #include <binder/ProcessState.h>
                                 ^
compilation terminated.
ERROR: libstagefright_h264 not found
```

I am using 
`NDK r10e-rc4` (64-bit),
`FFmpeg` source version 2.7
and `Ubuntu 14 64 bit`

Do I need to download android open source project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[binder/ProcessState.h](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/lollipop-mr1-release/include/binder/ProcessState.h) is part of AOSP, not the NDK.